# Difference between JToken.ToObject<T>() vs JToken.Value<T>()

Tags: c#, json, json.net

What is the difference between the `JToken.ToObject<T>()` method and the `JToken.Value<T>()` extension method (the one without the `key` parameter)?

```
var jToken = JToken.Parse("123");
var toObjectStrResult = jToken.ToObject<string>();
var valueStrResult = jToken.Value<string>();
// toObjectStrResult  == valueStrResult == "123"

var toObjectLongResult = jToken.ToObject<long>();
var valueLongResult = jToken.Value<long>();
// toObjectLongResult  == valueLongResult  == 123L
```

Comment: You can see for yourself here https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Linq/JToken.cs

Comment: [Value<T>](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken_Value__1.htm) requires a `key` parameter. It *doesn't* convert the token to an object they way `ToObject` does, it tries to find the (sub)token that matches the key and returns it

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I meant the Value<T>() extension method, the one without the `key` parameter, sorry for not mentioning it

Comment: @Darxis which one? Post the link

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I think it is that one https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Linq/Extensions.cs#L160

Comment: `Value<T>` is a **casting** type operation, it tries to convert the JSON token  to the selected type through casting or conversion operators.  `ToObject<T>` is a **deserialization** operation, it deserializes the JSON token to the specified type by invoking the serializer and using reflection.  As such `ToObject<>()` is more general,

Comment: @dbc Thanks for this info! Do you know when one should prefer using the first or the second one? Which one should I use when I know that the JToken is an integer and I would like to get its value?

Comment: @Darxis - `ToObject<>()` is the the most general, and will always work when deserialization to the target type is possible.  `Value<T>()` eventually calls `System.Convert.ChangeType()` so only works when the current JSON value is convertible to the desired value.  This can't be used in general (e.g. to deserialize objects) but might be more performant for, say, converting `long` values to `int`.

Comment: Should I make this an answer?

Comment: @dbc Sure! Also make sure to include that `Value<T>()` might be more performant in some cases, good to know this

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The difference is as follows:

1. [`ToObject<T>()`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/Overload_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken_ToObject.htm) is a **deserialization** operation.  It constructs a [`JsonSerializer`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonSerializer.htm) and uses it to deserialize the current `JToken` to the desired type.  As such the token could be anything (a JSON array, a JSON object, or a JSON primitive value) and the serializer will, using reflection, try to deserialize the token to the desired type by reading through its contents with a [`JTokenReader`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JTokenReader.htm).

   This method is useful when writing generic code where the input token and output type could be anything.  It is the most general and fail-safe way to create a c# object from a `JToken`.
2. [`Extensions.Value<U>(IEnumerable<JToken>)`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_Extensions_Value__1.htm) is a **conversion/casting** operation.  It attempts to convert the *value* of the current token to the target type by invoking [`Convert.ChangeType()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.convert.changetype) (as well as handling a few special cases).

   This method is useful when you know your `JToken` is, in fact, a [`JValue`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JValue.htm) and you want to convert its [`Value`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JValue_Value.htm) to a specific, required .Net primitive type.  For instance, if the `JValue` might contain a `long` or numeric string, you could convert it to an `int`, a `decimal` or a `double`.  If it might contain a `DateTime` or a string in [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format, you could convert it to a `DateTime`.  And any primitive JSON value can always converted to a string.

   While this method is less general than `ToObject<T>()` it will be more performant in converting primitive values since the serializer invokes the same conversion methods internally when deserializing a primitive.