# How to check if the value of a key is equal through out the list of JSON Object

Tags: c#, json, list, data-structures, json.net

I am trying input some validation in C#.
I have a LIST of JSON Object, and I want to add a validation that will check for a value of certain key and make sure they are all same in all the JSON object in the array.

LIST -

```
subtitles = [{ frameRate : '25', dropFrame: False}, { frameRate : '25', dropFrame: False}, { frameRate : '25', dropFrame: False}, { frameRate : '23', dropFrame: False}]
```

I want to add validation that will loop through every object and make sure that the value of the key `frameRate` is same through the array.

This is what i tried to do -  I created a aempty list and then tried to push all the frameRates and then looped through it and compared the value with previous one.

```
List<string> subtitleSegmentsFrameRates = new List<string>();

            foreach (var subtitle in segmentSubtitles) 
            {
                subtitleSegmentsFrameRates.Add(subtitle.frameRate);
                    
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < subtitleSegmentsFrameRates.Count; i++) {
                if (i != 0) {
                    if (subtitleSegmentsFrameRates[i] != subtitleSegmentsFrameRates[i - 1]) {
                        throw new CustomException("Frame Rates arocss segments do not match.");
                    }
                }
            }
```

Is there a better way to do this ?

Comment: Have you tried [deserializing to an anonymous object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6904825/deserialize-json-to-anonymous-object)?

Comment: Deserialize it and use `.Distinct(s => s.FrameRate).Count() == 1`.

Comment: JSON is a string, not a data structure. You need to parse that string into a data structure and query the data. You can use LINQ or a loop for brute-force searches, or use a container like Dictionary, HashSet, etc to accelerate specific queries

Comment: You can deserialize them using `Newtonsoft.Json` or other Json library and use loop, linq to iterate through all items and filter out what you need.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where did you stuck?

Comment: What I did was to create a list and then push all the frame rates into the list and then tried to compare each of the element with previous one.

Comment: I meant it on the code level. What have you written so far?

Comment: Edited the question, can you take a look at my approach ?

Comment: You could start your for loop from 1 instead of 0. You could also combine the for and foreach loops to avoid the population of the subtitleFragmentsFrameRates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can compare all the items against the first one after parsing input to `JArray` and linq `All` method

```
var jArray = JArray.Parse(subtitles);
bool allSame = jArray.All(j => j["frameRate"].Value<string>() == jArray[0]["frameRate"].Value<string>());
```

`j["frameRate"]` is type of `JToken` that's why to convert to string `.Value<string>()` is invoked over it.

Another way which is also suggested by @John:

```
bool same = jArray.Select(j => j["frameRate"].Value<string>()).Distinct().Count() == 1
```

Check this fiddle - https://dotnetfiddle.net/5xOJB5

Comment: `Value<string>` would be enough. You don't need to call `ToObject`. [Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58188277/difference-between-jtoken-toobjectt-vs-jtoken-valuet)

Answer (score 1):

First of all convert your json string into `JArray` and use [`.All()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.all?view=net-5.0) to check you have same value for `frameRate` property of all elements.

```
using System;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using System.Linq;

...
var validFrameRate = JArray.Parse(subtitles)  //Convert an Sub titles to JArray
           .All(x => x.Value<string>("frameRate") == "25");  //Check all frame rates are same or not.

Console.WriteLine(validFrameRate ? "Same frameRate in all elements" : "Different FrameRate in all elements");
```

[.Net Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/brTVHu)

---

`JArray` is an array of `JToken`, to get actual value you need to convert `JToken` to its actual type. Here we used `.Value<string>()` to get value of `frameRate` property of `JToken`

Comment: This won't compile: `x["frameRate"]` returns a `JToken` not a string.

Comment: @PeterCsala, thanks for your comment and keen observation. I fixed it.