# Object must implement IConvertible error when trying to cast dynamic object

Tags: c#, json.net

I am trying to cast a dynamic object into a named type which is actually a list. But I am getting an error

> The object must implement IConvertible

How to resolve that? Here is my function and its calling code

```cs
private static dynamic Cast(dynamic source,Type type)
{
    return Convert.ChangeType(source, type);
}

KipReport<dynamic> kr = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<KipReport<dynamic>>(responseBody, dateTimeConverter);
List<JsonTeamMaster> json731 = Cast(kr.Data, typeof( List<JsonTeamMaster>));
```

I also tried direct casting like this

```cs
List<JsonTeamMaster> json731 = (List<JsonTeamMaster>)kr.Data;
```

which trigger

> Unable to cast object of type
> 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Object]' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[EPMO_Toolset_API.common.JsonTeamMaster]'.

So could you please suggest which is the correct way of casting it?

---

Also if I am not using Dynamic object

```cs
KipReport<JsonTeamMaster> rpt731 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<KipReport<JsonTeamMaster>>(responseBody, dateTimeConverter);
List<JsonTeamMaster> json731 = (List<JsonTeamMaster>)rpt731.Data;
```

It's working fine and I am getting the data in json731.

Comment: `List<JsonTeamMaster> json731 = ((IEnumerable<object>)kr.Data).OfType<JsonTeamMaster>().ToList();`

Comment: Sorry its not triggering any error, but not returning anything to the jsonlist (json731(

Comment: What does `((IEnumerable<object>)kr.Data).FirstOrDefault().GetType()` return?

Comment: AssemblyQualifiedName: "Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject, Newtonsoft.Json, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed"
    Attributes: Public | BeforeFieldInit
    BaseType: {Name = "JContainer" FullName = "Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JContainer"}

Comment: The short answer is we will need a [mcve].

Comment: The fact that you are using `dynamic` is confusing things.  When you deserialize to `dynamic` Json.NET actually deserializes to some subclass of `JToken`.  If you want to then deserialize that `JToken` to some POCO you need to use `kr.Data.ToObject<List<JsonTeamMaster>>`.  See: [Difference between JToken.ToObject<T>() vs JToken.Value<T>()](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58188277/3744182).

Answer (score 0):

I think below method should help you.

```
LoginInfo objLoginInfo;
JsonSerializer serializer = new JsonSerializer();
JsonTextReader reader = new JsonTextReader(new 
System.IO.StringReader(LoginInfoString.ToString()));
reader.SupportMultipleContent = true;
objLoginInfo = serializer.Deserialize<LoginInfo>(reader);
```

Here LoginInfo is my class you can use here `dynamic` & i have passed `LoginInfoString` as json string that is being converting to class type.